# How to handle blank items when converting dates in R

Tags: r, na, missing-data, as.date

I have a csv download of data from a Management Information system. There are some variables which are dates and are written in the csv as strings of the format "2012/11/16 00:00:00".

After reading in the csv file, I convert the date variables into a date using the function as.Date(). This works fine for all variables that do not contain any blank items.

For those which do contain blank items I get the following error message:
"character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

How can I get R to replace blank items with something like "0000/00/00 00:00:00" so that the as.Date() function does not break? Are there other approaches you might recommend?

Comment: `as.Date(c("2012/11/16 00:00:00",NA))` works fine for me, so I assume you have something other than NAs in those blank fields. It would probably be best to change those blank fields to NAs. Could you post a subset of your data using `dput()`?

Comment: The data has either the date or a "" string. Here is the (condensed)output from dput(): structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("", "2012/10/04 00:00:00", 
"2012/10/09 00:00:00", "2012/10/15 00:00:00", "2012/11/02 00:00:00", 
"2012/11/12 00:00:00", "2012/11/15 00:00:00", "2012/11/16 00:00:00", 
"2012/11/19 00:00:00", "2012/11/30 00:00:00"), class = "factor")

Comment: see comment below my answer about factors ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're strings, does something as simple as

```
mystr <- c("2012/11/16 00:00:00","   ","")
mystr[grepl("^ *$",mystr)] <- NA
as.Date(mystr)
```

work?  (The regular expression `"^ *$"` looks for strings consisting of the start of the string (`^`), zero or more spaces (`*`), followed by the end of the string (`$`).  More generally I think you could use `"^[[:space:]]*$"` to capture other kinds of whitespace (tabs etc.)

Comment: be careful with factors, you may want to `as.character()` them first -- `grepl` may work strangely on factors.

Comment: It's wierd isn't it? How R defaults everything to factors when you use read.csv() to read in data. The grep seems to have worked. I'm just going through the resultant outputs to make sure it's worked ok.

Comment: OK thanks folks. The GREPL method seems to have worked really well.

Comment: you may be interested in `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` (see `?options` and `?read.csv`)

Answer (score 2):

Even better, have the NAs correctly inserted when you read in the CSV:

```
read.csv(..., na.strings='')
```

or to specify a vector of all the values which should be read as NA...

```
read.csv(..., na.strings=c('','  ','   '))
```